# Menu Separator Bars

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2019

I'm trying to code a menu bar using vba .net and the Microsoft visual studios 2019 processor. According to my textbook, if I right-click on an existing menu item and go to the insert section of the drop down menu there should be an option to add a separator bar. However when I go to do this there are only options to insert a menu item, a combobox, or a textbox. The alternative way of inserting one, by making a menu item's text property a hyphen, also does not work - it just shows up as a hyphen when I run the program. I need to have separator bars since it's a requirement of my project.

Here's an image of the insert menu that I get: 
[image]

Comment: Move one level down and the option will appear. There's no VBA.Net, the language is VB.Net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add a separator to the top level of a `MenuStrip`. Separators are only valid between drop-down items. Underneath that *Dorm Choices*, you can either type a dash and it will add a separator to the drop-down for that menu item or you can click the drop-down arrow in the editor and select *Separator*.